# Heroku Sites using SSL get a "B" on the SSL Labs Test

Tags: python, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

The test is here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest
You can see Heroku's grade here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=heroku.com . It gets a mix of "B"s and "A"s for different servers.

My site is [www.wealthypockets.com](https://www.wealthypockets.com/). You can my test results here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.wealthypockets.com -- a solid "B".

This is a two-part question:

1) Should I be concerned about not getting an "A" on this? Particularly about the "BEAST" attack and the DOS potential?

2) Is there anything I can do to get an improved score? Or this about waiting for Heroku to improve things?

Comment: Had look and never seen such a useless service telling nothing about how it derives its results. Maybe try another service.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the two parts separately:

1) It is very difficult to say if you should be concerned about not getting an A on this, because the requirements do not seem to be public.

BEAST attack is an interesting and somewhat complicated, but effective, attack which uses a vulnerability in SSLv3 and TLSv1.0. The attacker needs to be able to install a script to the user's browser and send known data over the SSL connection. The attacker also needs to be able to sniff the the connection and as a result can decrypt part of the following data. This has been fixed in TLSv1.1 and later, and many browsers have added protection against the BEAST attack by not sending all the requests to a particular server through the same channel.

2) I have just checked both the heroku.com and your website grades and they seem to be full A. I haven't found any information about how to tune Heroku SSL parameters, except for installing the certificate, so I believe this is not something you can control. I wouldn't be too concerned though, many SSL attacks are theoretical and BEAST is by far the worst (with maybe the renegotiation attack, but that is mostly patched server side). Your website seems to be quite simple with no way for the attacker to edit the content, so a BEAST attack should not be possible. It would be nice if Heroku preferred TLSv1.1 instead of TLSv1.0 though.